# JS Отключить в select 2 значение выбранное в select 1 и наоборот

Tags: javascript, jquery, chosen

Есть два списка (с мультивыбором) разной направленности но с одинаковым содержимым, если пользователь выбирает что-то в одном, то в другом он уже это не может выбрать, например:

1. список - люди, которые пришли
2. список - люди, которые не пришли

Но оба они содержат одинаковый список этих самых людей, и нужно выбрать.
Нашел на просторах похожий пример, но так и не могу разобраться как он работает и как его использовать в своих целях

[Ссылка на пример](https://jsfiddle.net/ba5b83th/)

Что есть у меня (CakePHP 3):

```
echo $this->Form->control('commission_members_present',['class'=>"chosen-select",
                                                                    'options'=>$commission_members,
                                                                    'multiple'=>true  ]);
echo $this->Form->control('commission_members_absent',['class'=>"chosen-select",
                                                                    'options'=>$commission_members,
                                                                    'multiple'=>true  ]);
```

[Здесь](https://jsfiddle.net/dkry3h7c/) можно посмотреть, что получается.

И как пример применить к моему случаю не понимаю... объясните пожалуйста или подскажите.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вот. уже сделанный. Взял часть с примера который готовый.

```
<div class="form-group select required">
<label class="control-label" for="commission-members-present">Члены комиссии, присутствующие</label>
<input type="hidden" name="commission_members_present" value=""/>
<select name="commission_members_present[]" multiple="multiple" class="chosen-select form-control" required="required" id="commission-members-present">
    <option value="4">фио1</option>
    <option value="5">фио2</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group select required">
<label class="control-label" for="commission-members-absent">Члены комиссии, отсутствующие</label>
<input type="hidden" name="commission_members_absent" value=""/>
<select name="commission_members_absent[]" multiple="multiple" class="chosen-select form-control" required="required" id="commission-members-absent">
    <option value="4">фио1</option>
    <option value="5">фио2</option>
</select>
```

```
    $(".chosen-select").chosen({
        max_selected_options: 5,
    no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
    width: "95%"
    });

 $(document).on('change','select.chosen-select',function() {
          var s = $('select.chosen-select'),
          val = +this.value, data = $(this).data('val');
          s.not(this).each(function(indx, el){
          data &&  $('option[value="'+data+'"]', el).prop('disabled', false)
          val && $('option[value="'+val+'"]', el).prop('disabled', true)
                  });
          $(this).data({val:val});
          $(this).next().val(val);
                    s.trigger("chosen:updated");
      });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5w8w4yb0/1/

Comment: Спасибо, изменений как оказалось немного, пробовал в этом духе сам, но так и не заработало( 
Буду разбираться как это работает.

Comment: Какой-то странный баг:  
в фидле отрабатывает все правильно, а вот у меня получается так, что я всегда во втором списке могу выбрать последнее значение которое остается, даже если оно выбрано в первом...